# EPOLLIN and send with no EPOLLOUT

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I've been able to use epoll successfully after your help and reading another resources, the problem I'm facing now is that I need to send to different FD than the EPOLLOUT event return, so if I have 5 FDs, then I need to send to 1 then to 4 then back to 1 then to 5 and so on based.

The following pseudo code is what I have now with both IN and OUT events,

```
 while(1) {

 rval = epoll_wait();

    for (i = 0; i < rval; i++) { 
     if (events & EPOLLOUT) {
        //send to the ready FD for sending
      }
     if (events & EPOLLIN) {
        //Receive from ready fd, this part is perfect for my application 
      }
    }
}
```

What I need to do is something like the following

```
char buff[100];
fd = read_data(buff); // read data ready to send, the return value is the FD the application should send the returned data to 

send(fd, buff, 100, 0);
```

and then I need the EPOLLIN to receive data from any FD because I'll be receiving from all fd all the time, I'm not sure how to do that, can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a layer of wrappage around every FD that can send: Let it have some state that says "ready", and a local data queue. Now make an interface that accepts data. If the state is not "ready", immediately enqueue the data and return. Otherwise attempt to send the data (in a loop), and if you hit EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, enqueue the rest and set "ready" to false.

Meanwhile, in your main event loop, whenever you get an EPOLLOUT, go into a `send` loop to drain the queue, and if you finish without error set "ready" to true. (With this logic, EPOLLOUT should only fire when your FD is not "ready", assuming you're in edge-triggered mode.)

Comment: I've been reading you post for a while now but I'm not sure how to do that :).